# How does font synchronization work on Windows

Tags: windows, fonts, synchronization

How does fonts sync work on Windows?
For example Adobe Type-Kit: is it actually writing fonts in `<system-drive>\Windows\Fonts\` folder or there is another way to initialize fonts in system from different location using Registry hacks?

Comment: Fonts don't have to be installed in the system "Fonts" folder, but if you're adding a font permanently, that's the most obvious place to put it.

Comment: You can add a font for the current session by calling [`AddFontResource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183326) and broadcasting a `WM_FONTCHANGE` message. You can permanently add it in the registry key "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts". Here's a [Python example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41841088/205580), which also gets font information via the undocumented function `GetFontResourceInfo`.

Comment: Note that if a font is installed anywhere other than the Fonts folder, it can't be removed or updated without rebooting the system.

Comment: Thanks for answers. @eryksun please post is as answer and I'll accept it. This is exactly what I was searching for. Thanks