# Installing font from TTF file

Tags: python, windows, fonts

I have tried to install a [font](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro/tree/release/TTF) I have in a ttf file in various ways using the many answers relating to this that I found on SO. Note: I have got the ttf file in the same folder as the code that I am running. I am trying to install this font so that I can use a mono-space font in `kivy`, so that tables format correctly. Here is what I tried:

1. I copied the function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41841088/7944165) answer and added: `install_font(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\python\SourceCodePro-Black.ttf')` on to the end of the code and ran it. I got an error. `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\WINDOWS\\Fonts\\SourceCodePro-Black.ttf'`
2. Tried to install it by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51177846/7944165) method. It successfully installed fonttools, but it did not manage to import it somehow. I tried importing both `fonttools` and `fontTools`.
3. I also had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25610343/7944165) answer but the comment underneath it suggested I shouldn't try that.

There doesn't seem to be a highly upvoted thread which details how to do this. What is the best method for doing this? Is it one of the above? And if so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It look like your script isn't running with administrative privileges. Don't know of any way for a script to increase its own rights.

Comment: The comment on #3 was just suggesting some shortcomings of the exact code, not implying that it was a bad approach.  I would probably attempt something similar if I were trying to do this.